# Limit at an endpoint of an interval on a piecewise function

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I've been struggling with a problem where I need to prove or disprove a statement that for a decreasing function $$f : [0,a] \rightarrow R$$ where $R$ is a set of real numbers and $a$ is a positive integer, there exists a limit at $x=0$.

From my understanding, if you have a counterexample of a  piecewise function where lets say $f(x)=10$ at $x=0$ and $-x $ at $x\in(0,a]$ then there is no limit at $x=0$ as you approach from above $0$ but I can't seem to be able to show it. Is the statement correct and I am wrong for trying to disprove it?

Comment: Well, first the limit at $0$ can only be considered from the right. Second, existence of a limit has nothing to do with the value of the function at the point in question. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Jose27 so if we have $f(x) = -x$ approaching the limit from the right towards x=0, it will approach 0 and at x=0, it jumps to 10 by the conditions of the function and since it jumps, it doesn't have a limit?

Comment: No, that's not quite right. You're confusing continuity with limit at a point. As you note in the first part, the limit of your example would be 0, then the jump would make the function not continuous, but it doesn't undo the fact that the limit does exist.

Comment: @Jose27 I am not quite sure I understand. For a limit to exist, both of limits from the right and left need to be equal to each other. If my function 
$$\begin{equation}
f(x)=\begin{cases}
          10 \quad &\text{if} \,  x=0 \\
          -x \quad &\text{if} \, x \in (0,a] \
     \end{cases}
\end{equation}$$
approaches $0$ from the right, it will have a value of $0$, while at $x=0$ it jumps to $10$. Surely that means that the limit doesn't exist since; $${ \lim_{x\to0} f(x) \ne f(0)}$$

Comment: IF you're looking at a two sided limit, then sure. But in the question, you can only look at the right limit, since the function is only defined on $[0,a]$.